# converting char** to char* or char

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings

I have a old program in which some library function is used and i dont have that library.

So I am writing that program using libraries of c++.
In that old code some function is there which is called like this

*string = newstrdup("Some string goes here");

the string variable is declared as char **string;

What he may be doing in that function named "newstrdup" ? 
I tried many things but i dont know what he is doing ... Can anyone help

Comment: Can you paste the newstrdup() function?

Comment: @tinkertim: "I have a old program in which some library function is used and i dont have that library"...

Comment: Can you paste any old code where newstrdup is used? Preferably inside a loop. Do you have a declaration for newstrdup from a .h file?

Comment: One more: Are there any other newstrXXXXX functions in this library? If so, do they conform to their stdlib functions? For example, a newstrpos or a newstrcmp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there has to be a reason that they wrote a "new" version of strdup. So there must be a corner case that it handles differently. like perhaps a null string returns an empty string.

litb's answer is a replacement for [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), but I would think there is a reason they did what they did.

If you want to use strdup directly, use a define to rename it, rather than write new code.

Comment: yep, since it is called "new"strdup, i think it uses operator new instead of malloc (strdup uses malloc). they may also have their own for portability reasons. i don't know :)

Comment: It may also be called newstrdup() simply because strdup() is not standard, although it is widely available, and they wanted to stay clear.  The use of 'newstrdup()' to indicate 'strdup-variant-using-new' is also plausible.

Comment: strdup() built in function is okay. but when i call the function using 
*response = newstrdup("Some String") i am getting segmentation fault.
what may be he reason for this and how to overcome?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the working code and of your testcases? Without more context, it's hard to say right now. Also, do you have the compiled library, since reversing it is also an option.

Answer (score 4):

The function is used to make a copy of c-strings. That's often needed to get a writable version of a string literal. They (string literals) are itself not writable, so such a function copies them into an allocated writable buffer. You can then pass them to functions that modify their argument given, like `strtok` which writes into the string it has to tokenize.

I think you can come up with something like this, since it is called ***new***strdup:

```
char * newstrdup(char const* str) {
    char *c = new char[std::strlen(str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(c, str);
    return c;
}
```

You would be supposed to free it once done using the string using

```
delete[] *string;
```

An alternative way of writing it is using `malloc`. If the library is old, it may have used that, which C++ inherited from C:

```
char * newstrdup(char const* str) {
    char *c = (char*) malloc(std::strlen(str) + 1);
    if(c != NULL) {
        std::strcpy(c, str);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Now, you are supposed to free the string using `free` when done:

```
free(*string);
```

Prefer the first version if you are writing with C++. But if the existing code uses `free` to deallocate the memory again, use the second version. Beware that the second version returns `NULL` if no memory is available for dup'ing the string, while the first throws an exception in that case. Another note should be taken about behavior when you pass a `NULL` argument to your `newstrdup`. Depending on your library that may be allowed or may be not allowed. So insert appropriate checks into the above functions if necessary. There is a function called `strdup` available in POSIX systems, but that one allows neither `NULL` arguments nor does it use the `C++` operator new to allocate memory.

Anyway, i've looked with google codesearch for `newstrdup` functions and found quite a few. Maybe your library is among the results:

[Google CodeSearch, newstrdup](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&start=10&sa=N&q=newstrdup)

Comment: i tried ur program like this.
i called newstrdup like this.
*ersponse = newstrdup(buffer) where buffer ="chaithra"
but while running it is giving as segmentation fault.

Comment: then i think you should add a null check: if str is NULL, just return NULL right away. because the only significant difference between the second and the POSIX strdup version is the check for null (beside the name, of course). would be a good reason for them to provide their own version.

Comment: ok.thanks its working if i call as 
response = newstrdup("some string"); where response is char*
but if response is char ** and if i call
*response=newstrdup("some string");
it is segmentation fault. 
may be i am not allocating memory thanks anyway

Comment: Chaithra, if course, you have to make your pointer point to somewhere. like  char *c; char **p = &c; then you can do  *p = newstrdup.... just doing char **p; *p = newstrdup... will write to some uncertain memory location and it will crash if you are lucky (or go silently wrong if you are not lucky)

Comment: if it is working if you do  char *c = newstrdup... then the function works fine. the bug then is with making the char** point to somewhere sensible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The line `*string = newstrdup("Some string goes here");` is not showing any weirdness to `newstrdup`. If `string` has type `char **` then `newstrdup` is just returning `char *` as expected. Presumably `string` was already set to point to a variable of type `char *` in which the result is to be placed. Otherwise the code is writing through an uninitialized pointer..

Answer (score 0):

newstrdup is probably making a new string that is a duplicate of the passed string; it returns a pointer to the string (which is itself a pointier to the characters).

Comment: Weird, why wouldn't it just return a pointer to the characters?

Comment: @Iraimbilanja: it appears to be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he's written a strdup() function to operate on an existing pointer, probably to re-allocate it to a new size and then fill its contents. Likely, he's doing this to re-use the same pointer in a loop where *string is going to change frequently while preventing a leak on every subsequent call to strdup().

I'd probably implement that like string = redup(&string, "new contents") .. but that's just me.

**Edit**:

Here's a snip of my 'redup' function which might be doing something similar to what you posted, just in a different way:

```
int redup(char **s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len, size;

    if (s2 == NULL)
        return -1;

    len = strlen(s2);
    size = len + 1;

    *s1 = realloc(*s1, size);

    if (*s1 == NULL)
        return -1;

    memset(*s1, 0, size);
    memcpy(*s1, s2, len);

    return len;
}
```

Of course, I should probably save a copy of *s1 and restore it if realloc() fails, but I didn't need to get that paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at what is happening with the "string" variable within the code as the prototype for the newstrdup() function would appear to be identical to the library strdup() version.

Are there any free(*string) calls in the code?

It would appear to be a strange thing do to, unless it's internally keeping a copy of the duplicated string and returning a pointer back to the same string again.

Again, I would ask why?

Comment: ya, I was thinking the same thing, there has to be some corner case it's handling differently :)